# Is there a way to fix error: 'Xamarin.Forms recommends TargetPlatformMinVersion >= 10.0.17763.0 (current project is -1)'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a problem when I want to upgrade a Xamarin app from Android 9.0 to Android 10.

```
/Users/user/.nuget/packages/xamarin.forms/4.8.0.1269/buildTransitive/Xamarin.Forms.targets(5,5): 
Warning: Xamarin.Forms recommends TargetPlatformMinVersion >= 10.0.14393.0 (current project is -1) (WeatherApp)
```

The error is on this part of the code:

```
 <Warning
    Text="Xamarin.Forms recommends TargetPlatformVersion &gt;= 10.0.17763.0 (current project is $(MicrosoftUIXamlTargetPlatformCheckValue))"
    Condition="$(MicrosoftUIXamlTargetPlatformCheckValue) &lt; 17763" />
```

I want to run this app on Android 10, but every clean build and run app on a real Android device app not responding every time.

Comment: So the App compilation stops with the Warning? This target doesn't seem to have anything to do with Android, but rather UWP, do you have a UWP project in your solution? If so could you try unload it?

Comment: I build this app on mac, but when I try to build on Windows machine may be there is heppaned something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been facing similar issue in release mode after lot of search I have found the fix that worked for me

Setting up the build configurations under configuration mapping to release worked for me

make sure all the release configuration build is checked under configuration mapping.

Answer (score 11):

There is a similar thread [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1251681/xamarinforms-application-warning.html).

And the **Solution** is:

I can confirm the issue has been fixed on the latest version of `Xamarin.Forms (4.8.0.1687)`. It is the SP5.

I recommend to update the nuget package.

Comment: this not solve the problem for my project, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it went away when I updated my `Xamarin.Forms` NuGet package to version `5.0.0.2545`: I just cleaned the whole solution and rebuild it after installing the update.